# How do I neatly present the output of different combinations of two factors in a table in r?

Tags: r

I have a dataset with 3 columns. The first two columns have the following input values from an experiment and are factors:

```
col1=[5,  5,  7,  5, 12,  7,  9,  9, 12, 12,  9,  7] 
col2=[3.0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.0, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0, 0.5, 1.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0]
```

The third column in the result of these combinations:

```
col3=[1.435078, 1.161110, 3.012732, 1.341047, 1.299615, 2.718960, 3.913285, 2.064090, 1.261958, 1.158850, 3.079639, 2.579303]
```

All I want is to present the data with the individual column2 values to the left of the table and column 1 values above the table, and the column 3 values pertaining to each unique combination of factors shown at the intersection of the both factors. Ideally, this would look something like this:

```
|     | 5    | 7    | 9    | 12   |
|-----|------|------|------|------|
| 0.5 | 1.16 | 2.72 | 3.91 | 1.30 |
| 1.0 | 1.34 | 3.01 | 2.06 | 1.26 |
| 3.0 | 1.43 | 2.58 | 3.08 | 1.16 |
```

What r function do I need to use to produce this simple data visualization? I've tried `table()`, `xtab()`, `list()`, and others, but I can't seem to figure it out after hours of googling.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `xtabs`:

```
xt <- xtabs(col3 ~ col2 + col1)
```

giving:

```
> xt
     col1
col2         5        7        9       12
  0.5 1.161110 2.718960 2.064090 1.299615
  1   1.341047 3.012732 3.913285 1.261958
  3   1.435078 2.579303 3.079639 1.158850
```

or use `ftable(xt)` to get slightly different output.

`tapply` would also work as an alternative to `xtabs`:

```
tapply(col3, data.frame(col2, col1), c)
```

If you want dashes around the cells then try:

```
library(Hmisc)
print.char.matrix(xt, col.names = TRUE)
```

giving:

```
+----+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|col2|    5   |    7   |    9   |   12   |
+----+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| 0.5| 1.16111| 2.71896| 2.06409|1.299615|
+----+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|   1|1.341047|3.012732|3.913285|1.261958|
+----+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|   3|1.435078|2.579303|3.079639| 1.15885|
+----+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

### Note

The input in reproducible form is:

```
col1 <- c(5,  5,  7,  5, 12,  7,  9,  9, 12, 12,  9,  7)
col2 <- c(3.0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.0, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0, 0.5, 1.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0)
col3 <- c(1.435078, 1.161110, 3.012732, 1.341047, 1.299615, 2.718960, 3.913285, 
  2.064090, 1.261958, 1.158850, 3.079639, 2.579303)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `dplyr` and `knitr`:

```
df %>%
  spread(col1, col3) %>%
  kable()

| col2|        5|        7|        9|       12|
|----:|--------:|--------:|--------:|--------:|
|  0.5| 1.161110| 2.718960| 2.064090| 1.299615|
|  1.0| 1.341047| 3.012732| 3.913285| 1.261958|
|  3.0| 1.435078| 2.579303| 3.079639| 1.158850|
```

Or just using `dplyr`:

```
df %>% 
  spread(col1, col3)

  col2        5        7        9       12
1  0.5 1.161110 2.718960 2.064090 1.299615
2  1.0 1.341047 3.012732 3.913285 1.261958
3  3.0 1.435078 2.579303 3.079639 1.158850
```

Or using `reshape2`:

```
dcast(df, col2 ~ col1, value.var = "col3") 

  col2        5        7        9       12
1  0.5 1.161110 2.718960 2.064090 1.299615
2  1.0 1.341047 3.012732 3.913285 1.261958
3  3.0 1.435078 2.579303 3.079639 1.158850
```

Data:

```
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(col1 = c(5,  5,  7,  5, 12,  7,  9,  9, 12, 12,  9,  7),
col2 = c(3.0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.0, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0, 0.5, 1.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0),
col3 = c(1.435078, 1.161110, 3.012732, 1.341047, 1.299615, 2.718960, 3.913285, 2.064090, 1.261958, 1.158850, 3.079639, 2.579303)))
```